# Google Places Autocomplete in UItextField using Swift

Tags: swift, uitextfield, google-places-api

I want to add the Google places autocomplete search suggestion just below UITextfield and I want latitude and longitude of the user. There will be two textfields i.e. pickup location and drop off location. Picture is attached for example. I have tried code but it did not show just below the uitextfield.

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMaps
import GooglePlaces
import GooglePlacePicker

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var pickupLocation: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.pickupLocation.delegate = self
}
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    let acController = GMSAutocompleteViewController()
    acController.delegate = self
    self.present(acController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
}

extension ViewController: GMSAutocompleteViewControllerDelegate {

// Handle the user's selection.
func viewController(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController, didAutocompleteWith place: GMSPlace) {
    print("Place name: \(place.name)")
    print("Place address: \(String(describing: place.formattedAddress))")
    print("Place attributions: \(String(describing: place.attributions))")
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func viewController(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController, didFailAutocompleteWithError error: Error) {
    // TODO: handle the error.
    print("Error: ", error.localizedDescription)
}

// User canceled the operation.
func wasCancelled(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController) {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

The sample picture is below attached
 [image]

Comment: Share what you have tried

Comment: I have edited my question. Please help me.

Comment: No one is answering